# Save NSDictionary in coreData

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdictionary

I have to store dictionary in core data. I never worked with core data before.

Can anyone help me out that how can I use core data in my existing project and use it to store Dictionary.

Comment: after some google i get to know that i have to do archive and un-archive for doing this. But i didn't know how to implement it in project.

Comment: have you seen [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211633/core-data-not-saving-transformable-nsmutabledictionary)

Comment: Check out: [insert NSDictionary into CoreData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682324/insert-nsdictionary-into-coredata)

Answer (score 5):

**NSDictionary into Core Data**   like that you need to do

```
 NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:yourDictionary forKey:@"dictpropertyinmanagedobject"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    [archiver release];
    [self.managedObject setValue:data forKey:@"dictpropertyinmanagedobject"];
```

**NSDictionary from Core Data**

```
NSData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[yourManagedObject valueForKey:@"dictpropertyinmanagedobject"]];
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
NSDictionary *yourDictionary=[[unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"dictpropertyinmanagedobject"] retain];
[unarchiver finishDecoding];
```

Comment: can i define self.managedObject in any class.??

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682324/insert-nsdictionary-into-coredata