# Cocoa bindings only working one way (NSMutableDictionary)

Tags: swift, macos, nsmutabledictionary, cocoa-bindings

I have a `ViewController` with a 'Note' object as an instance variable. This variable is set before the `ViewController` appears.

The `Note` object contains a `customFields` `NSMutableDictionary<String, String>`.
I bind each value of the dictionary to a `NSTextField` of the dictionary in `viewWillAppear` :

```
newTextField.bind(.value, to: self, withKeyPath: "note.customFields.\(key)", options: nil)
```

The textField correctly displays the value from `note.customFields.\(key)`.
BUT, if the user edits that value and saves, the change is not reflected in the dictionary.
The `save()` (basically a managedobjectcontext.save()) method has been tested with other fields (bound to other non-dictionary instance variables) and works properly.

Is there a reason why the dictionary does not receive the updated value?

Thanks for the help :-)

**EDIT**: here is the definition of customFields in the model:

[image]

Comment: What is "saves" and what are the "other fields"? Are `note` and `customFields` KVO compliant? Please post a [mve].

Comment: `Note` is a NSManagedObject. `customFields` is a `NSMutableDictionary` instance, so KVO-compliant by default. The `save()` is basically a `NSManagedObjectContext.save()`. The other fields in `Note` are Strings, NSNumbers, ... (various NSManagedObject properties).

Comment: Did the text field end editing?

Comment: Yes it is, I verified :/

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the combination of mutable type (here `NSMutableDictionary`) and Core Data.

This post helped: [Core Data not saving transformable NSMutableDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211633/core-data-not-saving-transformable-nsmutabledictionary)

And this article helped as well: https://medium.com/@rohanbhale/hazards-of-using-mutable-types-as-transformable-attributes-in-core-data-2c95cdc27088

**Solution summary**

As proposed in the first link up-mentioned, I tried informing Core Data of changes in my `NSMutableDictionary` using `note.valueDidChange(forKey: "customFields")` but it **did not work** properly.

So I ended up using the second proposition in the first link, which is the same as the solution proposed in the second linked:

- Use a `NSDictionary` as transformable type
- When you need to modify this dictionary, use `mutableDict = dictionary.mutableCopy()`, and then save back to the nsdictionary : `dictionary = mutableDict.copy()`
- For the specific case of `NSTextField` binding, the bindings will work for displaying the value, but for updating the value, you have to do it without bindings (whenever your view will disappear or when textfield ends editing)

Hope that helps!